# How to select child element using parent element id in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to select child element using parent element id in CSS?
can i select like this?

```css
#intro p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="intro">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you can and you can see from your example it's working

Comment: Any basic tutorial on CSS would have answered this question; so what made you ask? Are you having a problem of some sort with your CSS selectors, or their specificity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works fine. If you want to select direct children, you can use:

```
#intro > p {
  color: red;
}
```